# S3 bucket creation with encryption is failing because of AWSSamples::S3BucketEncrypt::Hook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, hook

I have activated **AWSSamples::S3BucketEncrypt::Hook** with the following configuration but S3 bucket creation with encryption enabled seems to be failing because of the hook.

```
{
  "CloudFormationConfiguration": {
    "HookConfiguration": {
      "TargetStacks": "ALL",
      "FailureMode": "FAIL",
      "Properties": {
        "minBuckets": "1",
        "encryptionAlgorithm": "AES256"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "CloudFormationConfiguration": {
    "HookConfiguration": {
      "TargetStacks": "ALL",
      "FailureMode": "FAIL",
      "Properties": {
        "minBuckets": "1",
        "encryptionAlgorithm": "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Hook Configuration]

[image: Hook]

The following CloudFormation stacks are supposed to pass but they are failing. They only seem to work when I disable the hook. I have checked the trust policy, which seems fine for CloudFormation to access the hook and S3 bucket.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: S3 bucket with default encryption
Resources:
  EncryptedS3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub 'encryptedbucket-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::AccountId}'
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: 'AES256'
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
```

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: This CloudFormation template provisions an encrypted S3 Bucket
Resources:
  EncryptedS3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub 'encryptedbucket-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::AccountId}'
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: 'aws:kms'
              KMSMasterKeyID: !Ref EncryptionKey
            BucketKeyEnabled: true
      Tags: 
        - Key: "keyname1"
          Value: "value1"

  EncryptionKey:  
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
     Description: KMS key used to encrypt the resource type artifacts
     EnableKeyRotation: true
     KeyPolicy:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
      - Sid: Enable full access for owning account
        Effect: Allow
        Principal: 
          AWS: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
        Action: kms:*
        Resource: "*"

Outputs:
  EncryptedBucketName:
    Value: !Ref EncryptedS3Bucket
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple issues

1. The role need to be created using https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-samples/blob/main/hooks/python-hooks/s3-bucket-encryption/hook-role.yaml
2. CF Hook Configuration need to be the following
3. KMS

```
{
  "CloudFormationConfiguration": {
    "HookConfiguration": {
      "TargetStacks": "ALL",
      "FailureMode": "FAIL",
      "Properties": {
        "minBuckets": "1",
        "encryptionAlgorithm": "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3.1 Use the following CF to create SSE-S3 bucket for point no 3

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: This CloudFormation template provisions an encrypted S3 Bucket
Resources:
  EncryptedS3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub 'encryptedbucket-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::AccountId}'
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: 'aws:kms'
              KMSMasterKeyID: !Ref EncryptionKey
            BucketKeyEnabled: true
      Tags: 
        - Key: "keyname1"
          Value: "value1"

  EncryptionKey:  
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
     Description: KMS key used to encrypt the resource type artifacts
     EnableKeyRotation: true
     KeyPolicy:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
      - Sid: Enable full access for owning account
        Effect: Allow
        Principal: 
          AWS: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
        Action: kms:*
        Resource: "*"

Outputs:
  EncryptedBucketName:
    Value: !Ref EncryptedS3Bucket
```

OR

4. SSE-S3

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: S3 bucket with default encryption
Resources:
 EncryptedS3Bucket:
   Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
   Properties:
     BucketName: !Sub 'aesencryptedbucket-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::AccountId}'
     BucketEncryption:
       ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
         - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
             SSEAlgorithm: AES256
   DeletionPolicy: Delete
```

4.1 Use the following CF to create SSE-S3 bucket for point no 4

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: This CloudFormation template provisions an encrypted S3 Bucket
Resources:
  EncryptedS3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub 'encryptedbucket-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::AccountId}'
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: 'AES256'
            BucketKeyEnabled: true
      Tags: 
        - Key: "keyname1"
          Value: "value1"
```

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation template for S3 bucket with condition based encryption is:

```
# version: 1.0
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Create standardized S3 bucket using CloudFormation Template

Parameters:
  BucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: "Name of the S3 bucket"
  KMSKeyArn:
    Type: String
    Description: "KMS Key Arn to encrypt S3 bucket"
    Default: ""
  SSEAlgorithm:
    Type: String
    Description: "Encryption algorithm for KMS"
    AllowedValues:
      - aws:kms
      - AES256

Conditions:
  AES256: !Equals [!Ref SSEAlgorithm, "AES256"]

Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      BucketEncryption: 
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration: 
        - !If
          - AES256
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: !Ref SSEAlgorithm
            BucketKeyEnabled: true
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: !Ref SSEAlgorithm
              KMSMasterKeyID: !Ref KMSKeyArn
            BucketKeyEnabled: true
```

Using the code above you can either use Customer managed KMS key or AWS Managed key depending on it's use without drifting the stack. The property `KMSMasterKeyID` is not available for AWS managed encryption (SSE-S3).